# Parent polygon in Leaflet js

Tags: javascript, leaflet, openstreetmap

I would like to wrap multiple polygons in a parent polygon. Example below:

[image]

Is this possible in Leaflet js? Assume I have an array of `L.polygon` objects.

Thank you

Answer (score 5):

Short answer: no.

If you want to create an envelope for your polygones, then it is an algorithm problem that goes beyond the scope of leafletjs.

You can look at the answers of this [question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/5426/how-to-find-the-boundary-co-ordinates-from-a-given-set-of-co-ordinates) to start solving your problem.

EDIT: here is an [example](http://plnkr.co/edit/xj9EGPZP1oudLkgunSTt?p=preview) using Turfjs library (thanks to @IvanSanchez for the heads up and to @HudsonPH for the polygons).

```
// draw envelope
var points = {
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features":
[
 // collect the points of your polygons
 turf.point([-104.05, 48.99]),
 // ...
]
};

var hull = turf.convex(points);
L.geoJson(hull).addTo(map);
```

Comment: I think the easiest way of approaching this problem in a Leaflet environment is to use the Turf library and its [convex hull capabilities](http://turfjs.org/docs/#convex). Obviously it's good to know there are other algorithms and approaches.

Answer (score 1):

You can have a group, but you need define all the coordinates
more info: http://leafletjs.com/examples/geojson.html

```
    var states = [{
    "type": "Feature",
    "properties": {"party": "Republican"},
    "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [[
            [-104.05, 48.99],
            [-97.22,  48.98],
            [-96.58,  45.94],
            [-104.03, 45.94],
            [-104.05, 48.99]
        ]]
    }
}, {
    "type": "Feature",
    "properties": {"party": "Democrat"},
    "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [[
            [-109.05, 41.00],
            [-102.06, 40.99],
            [-102.03, 36.99],
            [-109.04, 36.99],
            [-109.05, 41.00]
        ]]
    }
}];

L.geoJson(states, {
    style: function(feature) {
        switch (feature.properties.party) {
            case 'Republican': return {color: "#ff0000"};
            case 'Democrat':   return {color: "#0000ff"};
        }
    }
}).addTo(map);
```